# Add a break then a span after the first word of an anchor using Jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation, anchor, html, break

I've taken a look at a lot of the questions but couldnt find relevant code to help me.  Most of the questions people have asked want a span after the first word but i need to dynamically input a `<br />` AND then wrap the rest of the text in a span after the first word of a nav anchor link.  Also this will only affect the first (parent) level of li/anchors.

Here is the html:

```
<nav id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">

<ul>

<li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home our main page</a></li>

<li><a href="blog.html">Blog latest events</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="single.html">Single</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="about.html">About company, team</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services we offer services</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I want the code to spit out like this:

```
<nav id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">

<ul>

<li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home  <br /><span>our main page</span></a></li>

<li><a href="blog.html">Blog  <br /><span>latest events</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="single.html">Single</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="about.html">About  <br /><span>company, team</span></a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services  <br /><span>we offer services</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: apologies for the messed up HTML ... arrgh .... the wysiwyg code helper isnt very clear or helpful :P

Comment: It isn't a wysiwyg editor. It's a [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) editor, and you should learn to use it because it's vastly superior to wysiwyg.

Comment: sorry for the first time posting nooby issues ... i've read alot of posts on this site but never really posted before so the editor thingy was a bit difficult ... i know html but the instructions arent clear so dont shoot the messenger!  :P
heres the link to what i was working on : http://jsfiddle.net/9wPaF/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little something like this:

```
$("nav > ul > li > a").html(function(i, oldVal) {
   return oldVal.replace(/ .*/, function(match) {
                                   return "<br><span>" + match + "</span>";
   });
});
```

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NUReJ/

(The above will put the space inside the `<span>` rather than before the `<br>`, like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="current">Home<br><span> our main page</span>
```

...but the browser will render it the same way. Or you can take the basic idea and modify it to suit yourself...)